# Will "vagrant box update" destroy my current VM?

Tags: vagrant

as described on the title, will `vagrant box update` destroy my current VM? My current vagrant VM is a little too fragile and needs some time to setup after it has been destroyed.

On each `vagrant up` I get a message, that a newer version of my base box is available, but I hesitate to do so, because I need the current setup of my VM for daily work.

Am I safe to update?

Comment: My MySQL databases seem to be missing after `vagrant box update` ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/60286908/470749 ), so I won't be doing that in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

short answer is no `vagrant box update` only downloads and installs the new box it will NOT update any of your running Vagrant VMs.

You get the "new version box" message because check for updates on `vagrant up` is enabled by default. If you don't want to see it you can modify your Vagrant file by adding following line

```
config.vm.box_check_update = false
```

You have to explicitly destroy your machine and recreate it to use the updated box. Vagrant will NOT do that on its own.